# MM! file in every directory

Tags: file-association, ms-dos

There's a file called `MM!` in every directory in DOS 6.22. Just `MM!`, no file extension... What causes this?

Comment: I'll take "Computer Viruses" for $200, Alex.

Comment: I agree with *msw* here.  There is no documented reason for this behaviour.

Comment: I didn't know DOS 6.22 even existed any more.

Comment: HK1:  Most people have upgraded to FreeDOS:  http://www.freedos.org/

Comment: Can you examine the contents of one of these MM! files?

Answer (score 2):

If your DOS 6.22 system has network file-sharing enabled and it's file-shares are accessed from a Windows system that is running some file management/cataloging software, it is possible the  software creates the "MM!" files to keep track of some metadata such as the archiving policies for each folder or a history of actions taken.

This is pure speculation based on Googling for "MM file", noting certain interesting results and  thinking about the way products like Picasa (not the culprit) create metatdata files in each folder.